# How we test ARCore apps on device farm like AWS or App Center?

Tags: automation, augmented-reality, ui-automation, aws-device-farm, visual-studio-app-center-test

I want to write a testing script to test the Android/iOS app which is using Augment Reality so that I can run the tests over `AWS` or `App Center`.

How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to test on your AR app. You can test any UI features of your app, but AWS Device Farm does not support any external input. You will not be able to connect the device to a controller, a headset, and you will not be able to physically move the device. You can turn on the camera, but you will not be able to see anything out of it.

Comment: I want to check that by placing a 3d object in the AR app scene view is working properly or not with some gestures input.

Comment: In general AWS Device Farm supports gestures. As long as long as your AR app scene isn't dependent on the camera picking up anything specific it should work.

They do offer 1000 free minutes when starting off (see https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/) I would suggest writing up an automation test and try running it on AWS Device Farm.